# Issues with UITableView loading Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitableview

I am working on an app that is downloading a bunch of JSON information then presenting it in a UITableView, using Core Data to store all the information. I'm currently having an issue with the loading of elements in the tableView - whenever I scroll (I've played with different row heights, no difference) I can see the `nameLabel` property as in my code below change before my eyes to names that should not be represented in that row.

In my other views that have images in the cell, the same thing happens, with the images getting muddled up constantly. Also, the tableView doesn't even show the data (that is there, waiting) until I touch it and scroll. This is the code I have:

```
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.managedObjectContext = [Pro downloadStoreData];
}

- (void)setManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    _managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Pro"];

    request.predicate = nil;
    request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:NO]];

                                self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Pro Cell"];

    Pro *pro = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *proImageView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:2];
    UILabel *ageLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:3];
    UILabel *yearsLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:4];
    UILabel *locationLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:5];

    nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo Slab" size:18.0f];
    nameLabel.text = pro.title;
    //[cell setNeedsDisplay];
    //NSLog(@"%@", pro.title);



    return cell;
}
```

As you can see I kickoff the download in another class, then set the context and use an `NSFetchedResultsController` to get the info.

I have attempted combinations of `[cell setNeedsDisplay]` and `[self.tableView reloadData]`, but it doesn't change the effect.

I do have one UITableView that works, fine, but I cannot figure out what makes that unique to the others.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should call `performFetch:` method on your `fetchedResultsController` an then reload your `tableView`.

```
NSError *error = nil;
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

It looks like your `downloadStoreData` is a synchronous method, so that should work for you, but if you are fetching the data asynchronously consider making your `viewController` a delegate of `fetchedResultsController`.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned - the TableView I'm using is a subclass of a TableView made to work with Core Data already, so once I set the `fetchedResultsController` it automatically called `performFetch` and `reloadData`.

I tried also making the controller a delegate and still no luck - same result when scrolling/loading.

Comment: Try calling `[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]`. Are there any?

Comment: Yep I can use an `NSLog` to find any of the properties on the fetched objects and the returned array is obviously not nil as it returns values.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my problem was - I was calling

```
(UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```

rather than

```
(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
```

So I believe the view was mixing up all the different UI objects with different cells and generally getting confused.

I hope this helps someone!